# Pandas, search for results in another column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas library to read data from a .json file. I have the following example dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['1', 'book1'],
                   ['1', 'book2'],
                   ['1', 'book6'],
                   ['2', 'book1'],
                   ['2', 'book6'],
                   ['2', 'book3'],
                   ['3', 'book4'],
                   ['3', 'book2'],
                   ['4', 'book3'],
                  ],
                  columns=['visitor_id', 'bookid'])
```

This dataset shows the user_id and which book this user has read. My question is, is it possible to filter out the list of books other users have read based on a given book value? For example, which other books other users have read which also read book 1. So the result should have 'book6', 'book3' and 'book2' if I were to search for 'book1'.

Is it possible to do it directly using any pandas function? The closest I could find in the documentation was groupby() function but I could not get it to work. I want to avoid going through each value using a loop as my dataset is quite big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter all `visitor_id` where is match mask `m` for compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), then filter original `visitor_id` with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and last filter all groups without `m` mask by inverted it by `~` to Series, then to unique list:

```
m = df['bookid'].eq('book1')
a = df.loc[df['visitor_id'].isin(df.loc[m, 'visitor_id']) & ~m, 'bookid'].unique().tolist()
print (a)
['book2', 'book6', 'book3']
```

Or you can use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for test at least one match per groups:

```
m = df['bookid'].eq('book1')
a = df.loc[m.groupby(df['visitor_id']).transform('any')  & ~m, 'bookid'].unique().tolist()
print (a)
['book2', 'book6', 'book3']
```

**Explanation**:

First compare values to boolean mask:

```
m = df['bookid'].eq('book1') 
print (m)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
Name: bookid, dtype: bool
```

Then filter `visitor_id` it is combination [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[m])
  visitor_id bookid
0          1  book1
3          2  book1
```

with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter by mask and column name, here `visitor_id` to `Series`:

```
print (df.loc[m, 'visitor_id'])
0    1
3    2
Name: visitor_id, dtype: object
```

Now filter again by values from `Series` for get all rows by groups:

```
print (df['visitor_id'].isin(df.loc[m, 'visitor_id']))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
Name: visitor_id, dtype: bool
```

But because want remove rows with mask `m`, first invert mask for True->False, False->True mapping:

```
print (~m)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
Name: bookid, dtype: bool
```

And chain by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
print (df['visitor_id'].isin(df.loc[m, 'visitor_id']) & ~m)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
dtype: bool bookid
```

This mask is used for filter `bookid` column:

```
print (df.loc[df['visitor_id'].isin(df.loc[m, 'visitor_id']) & ~m, 'bookid'])
1    book2
2    book6
4    book6
5    book3
Name: bookid, dtype: object
```

And last is convert `Series` to unique array and to list:

```
print (df.loc[df['visitor_id'].isin(df.loc[m, 'visitor_id']) & ~m, 'bookid'].unique().tolist())
['book2', 'book6', 'book3']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Would it be possible to explain what this ~ does? I am new to pandas so I don't understand what it means.

Comment: @NaeemKhan - Added explanation